# Difference between translatable="false" and <xliff:g>

Tags: android, xml

I was using translatable="false" in the past to avoid translate all strings but when I've searched best practices for the usage of the string then I've found this way

```
<string name="PhraseApp">
<xliff:g id="company">PhraseApp</xliff:g>is a localization company.
</string>
```

but in that blog not clear the difference or pros and cons to choose between them. guide me if someone know about it.

Comment: [Why use XLIFF?](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/xliff/faq.php#WhyUseXLIFF)

Answer (score 0):

XLIFF is a specification for the loss-less interchange of localizable data and its related information.

But question is 'what is the difference between "localisation" and "translation"?'

Translation is the act of rendering text into another language.

Localisation is a special kind of translation that takes into account the culture of the location or region where the translated text is expected to be used.

For example, although English is spoken in both the United Kingdom and the USA, differences in wording exist on either side of the Atlantic Ocean. Take for example the UK spelling of "localisation", which is "localization" in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

In standard localization tools and those which process XLIFF, the following text will be exposed for translation (i.e. not protected):

"PhraseApp is a localization company."

Depending on how the file is processed during translation, the translator will see tags before and after "PhraseApp" - or "PhraseApp" will be separated into another segment for translation, which you do not want.

In this situation to ensure "PhraseApp" is not changed during translation there are two methods:
1. Replace "PhraseApp" with a placeholder - the translator will see the placeholder but cannot edit the placeholder itself, and the placeholder can be moved into the appropriate location in the translated string.
2. Create a Glossary of terms which should not be translated. In good localization software, glossaries can be loaded to the translation workspace - if a translation conflicts with the glossary (in this case, if PhraseApp is changed) then an warning is issued to the translator.

If anything above is unclear please let me know.